# How to add space after/before '{' and '}' in WebStorm?

Tags: typescript, react-native, webstorm, tsx

I am a bit familiar with JetBrains products and I know I can set style for the files I am working on. However, I am not able to find where to configure my .tsx file in order to see my desired style. Seems, changes in TypeScript section doesn't change my .tsx file.

As you can see in the following image, I have .tsx file and I want to have space after `{`, before `}` and before `/>`. However, my all spaces gets removed after I hit <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: 1) IDE version? 2) Space before `/>` -- might be controlled by "In empty tag" option in HTML (or maybe even XML); 3) After/Before `{}` -- see `Other | Within interpolation expressions` on `Spaces` tab for TypeScript -- might be it (sorry, cannot be more precise as I'm not a JavaScript person).

Comment: Awesome, I wish you could put your comment as answer. All works very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the option **Within interpolation expressions** (works in WS2017.2) in *Preferences -> Editor -> Code style -> TypeScript*:

[image: Within interpolation expression]

Answer (score 1):

On web storm 2021.2
Just go to Preferences -> Editor -> Code style -> TypeScript
[image]

Answer (score 0):

GO to `Preferences -> Editor -> Code style -> TypeScript`.
The configuration options are in there although, they won't have all of the preferences you mention but they do have things like Space within braces etc

[Webstorm CodeStyle DOCS](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/code-style-typescript.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have `Object litral type braces` and `Object literal braces` checked in `Spaces` tab of `TypeScript` section. However, seems those are not getting used in my file. That's why I assumed this section only applyes rules to `.ts` files rather than `.tsx` files.

Comment: Yes I think that might be the case with web storm. Have you tried switching the extension to see the effects? Although if you really want to work with `.tsx` you could file for the feature on you want on [http://youtrack.jetbrains.com](http://Jetbrain%20Youtrack)